# Plotting discrete points on a phase plot

Tags: plotting, complex, parametric-functions

I'm trying to generate a phase plot of a sinusoidal voltage at discrete points using the following code:

```
ListPlot[Table[{5*Sin[n*π/4 + π/3], 5*Cos[n*π/4 + π/3]}, {n, 8}],
         AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"Real", "Imaginary"}, PlotLabel -> "Plot 1d"]
```

I would also like to make it so there is an arrow that originates at the origin and ends at each point on the plane. Also, I would like to label each point with its corresponding value of n. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @belisarius thank you for this excellent introductory advice. I certainly would have valued this with my first encounter. It seems a comment that should be reproduced (with attribution).

Comment: @ubpdqn A pity you haven't got one of them. Here is the full set http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/597/193 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
t = Table[{n, 5*Sin[n*π/4 + π/3], 5*Cos[n*π/4 + π/3]}, {n, 8}]; 
ListPlot[t[[All, 2 ;;]], AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"Real", "Imaginary"}, 
         PlotLabel -> "Plot 1d", PlotRangePadding -> 2.8] /. 
         Point@x_ :> ({Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}], Text[Nearest[Thread[N@t[[All, 2 ;;]] -> 
                      t[[All, 1]]], #], 1.2 #]} & /@ x)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I meant by the arrows, but I meant for the data point labels to represent the parametric x values, (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8). I apologize. I shouldn't have used x as the parametric variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please clarify what you did?

Comment: @CrawdadMan sorry, no time today. Perhaps someone else can